# Requesting Permissions at runtime doesn't work

Tags: android

I tried to request a permission at runtime like it is explained at  the [android developer page](http://http:https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html//).

But it doesn't work for me. I only get a dialog with my explanation. No Dialog to grant or deny the permission.

My Activity code is the following:

```
package de.gerding.test.dbperformancemessung;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import de.gerding.test.dbperformancemessung.Diagramme.ShowSizeGraphActivity;
import de.gerding.test.dbperformancemessung.Diagramme.ShowTimeGraphActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    //View Elemente
    private Button         button_mainactivity_start_evaluation,button_mainactivity_show_ergebniise,button_mainactivity_show_timegraph,button_mainactivity_show_sizegraph;
private TextView textview_mainactivity_state_display;

//Debug Parameter
public static boolean logging = true;

//Ergebnisse
private long[] couchdurations = null; //= new long[]{134,56,396,970,1943};
private long[] couchsizes = null;
private long[] perstdurations = null; //= new long[]{38, 283, 546, 1445,2719};
private long[] perstsizes = null;
private long[] sqlitedurations = null; //= new long[]{60,447,4538,11523,19981};
private long[] sqlitesizes = null;


//Sonstige Variablen
private Context ctx;
private int progressstate = 0;
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1001;
private Activity thisActivity;

//Servicezeugs
public static String ServiceResponseTag = "ServiceResponse";
public static final String CouchTimesTag = "couchtimes";
public static final String CouchSizesTag = "couchsizes";
public static final String PerstTimesTag = "persttimes";
public static final String PerstSizesTag = "perstsizes";
public static final String SQLiteTimesTag = "sqlitetimes";
public static final String SQLiteSizesTag = "sqlitesizes";
private ResponseReceiver responsereceiver;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    thisActivity = this;
    button_mainactivity_start_evaluation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mainactivity_start_evaluation);
    button_mainactivity_start_evaluation.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_mainactivity_show_ergebniise = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mainactivity_show_ergebnisse);
    button_mainactivity_show_ergebniise.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_mainactivity_show_timegraph = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mainactivity_show_timediagram);
    button_mainactivity_show_timegraph.setEnabled(false);
    button_mainactivity_show_timegraph.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_mainactivity_show_sizegraph = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mainactivity_show_dbsizediagram);
    button_mainactivity_show_sizegraph.setEnabled(false);
    button_mainactivity_show_sizegraph.setOnClickListener(this);
    ctx = this;
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    checkPermissions();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    log("Gerding", "onClick(View v");
    Intent intent;
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button_mainactivity_start_evaluation:
            log("Gerding", "Start Evaluation");
            intent = new Intent(this, EvaluationService.class);
            this.startService(intent);
            //ergebnisArraysInitialisieren();
            progressstate = 0;
            progressDialog  = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            progressDialog.setMax(28);
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Evaluation läuft");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Evaluation wurde gestartet");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            button_mainactivity_show_timegraph.setEnabled(false);
            button_mainactivity_show_sizegraph.setEnabled(false);
            //initData();
            break;
        case R.id.button_mainactivity_show_timediagram:
            log("Gerding", "Show TimeGraph");
            if((couchdurations != null) && (perstdurations != null) && (sqlitedurations != null))
            {
                intent = new Intent(this, ShowTimeGraphActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.CouchTimesTag, couchdurations);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PerstTimesTag, perstdurations);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteTimesTag, sqlitedurations);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Es muss erst evaluiert werden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button_mainactivity_show_dbsizediagram:
            if((couchdurations != null) && (perstdurations != null) && (sqlitedurations != null))
            {
                intent = new Intent(this, ShowSizeGraphActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.CouchSizesTag, couchsizes);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PerstSizesTag, perstsizes);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteSizesTag, sqlitesizes);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Es muss erst evaluiert werden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button_mainactivity_show_ergebnisse:
            intent = new Intent(this, ErgebnisActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.CouchTimesTag, couchdurations);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.CouchSizesTag, couchsizes);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PerstTimesTag, perstdurations);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PerstSizesTag, perstsizes);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteTimesTag, sqlitedurations);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteSizesTag, sqlitesizes);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "de.gerding.intent.action.serviceanswer";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getStringExtra(ServiceResponseTag).equalsIgnoreCase("State"))
        {
            progressstate ++;
            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progressDialog.setMessage(intent.getStringExtra("State"));
                progressDialog.setProgress(progressstate);
            }
            log("Gerding", "new State:  " + intent.getStringExtra("State"));
        }else if(intent.getStringExtra(ServiceResponseTag).equalsIgnoreCase("ENDE"))
        {
            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            button_mainactivity_show_timegraph.setEnabled(true);
            button_mainactivity_show_sizegraph.setEnabled(true);
            couchdurations = intent.getLongArrayExtra(MainActivity.CouchTimesTag);
            couchsizes = intent.getLongArrayExtra(MainActivity.CouchSizesTag);
            perstdurations = intent.getLongArrayExtra(MainActivity.PerstTimesTag);
            perstsizes = intent.getLongArrayExtra(MainActivity.PerstSizesTag);
            sqlitedurations = intent.getLongArrayExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteTimesTag);
            sqlitesizes = intent.getLongArrayExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteSizesTag);

            new writeToFileTask().execute();

            intent = new Intent(ctx, ErgebnisActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.CouchTimesTag, couchdurations);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.CouchSizesTag, couchsizes);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PerstTimesTag, perstdurations);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PerstSizesTag, perstsizes);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteTimesTag, sqlitedurations);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SQLiteSizesTag, sqlitesizes);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(responsereceiver);
}
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    responsereceiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    registerReceiver(responsereceiver, filter);
}
public static void log(String logTag, String logtext)
{
    if(logging)
    {
        Log.i(logTag, logtext);
    }
}
private class writeToFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>
{
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Log.i("Gerding", "Filewrite is started");

        //Write File
        String state;
        File file;
        state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
        {
            File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath()+"/DBEvaluation");
            if(!Dir.exists())
            {
                Dir.mkdir();
            }
            //Datetime
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy_HH_mm_ss");
            String filename = simpleDate.format(date);
            file = new File(Dir, filename + ".txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            String zeile = "";
            long[] datasizes = new long[]{
                    10000,
                    10000,
                    10000,
                    10000,
                    10000,
                    1000,
                    10000,
                    100000};
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                zeile = "Fahrt\tDatensätze\tCouchbase\tPerst\tSQLite\n";
                fos.write(zeile.getBytes());
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    zeile = (i+1) + "\t" + datasizes[i]+ "\t" + couchdurations[0] + "\t" + perstdurations[0] + "\t" + sqlitedurations[i] + "\n";
                    fos.write(zeile.getBytes());
                }
                zeile = "\n\n";
                fos.write(zeile.getBytes());
                zeile = "Fahrt\tDatensätze\tCouchbase\tPerst\tSQLite\n";
                fos.write(zeile.getBytes());
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    zeile = (i+1) + "\t" + datasizes[i]+ "\t" + couchsizes[0] + "\t" + perstsizes[0] + "\t" + sqlitesizes[i] + "\n";
                    fos.write(zeile.getBytes());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else
        {
            //ERROR
        }
        Log.i("Gerding", "Filewrite is finished");
        return 0l;
    }
}
public void checkPermissions()
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Zugriff auf den externen Speicher wird benötigt um Daten in eine Datei schreiben zu können.").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                //do things
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
        //}
    }
    /*// Quick permission check
    int permissionCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
    permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
    if (permissionCheck != 0) {

        this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
    }*/
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
        {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // task you need to do.
            }else
            {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                this.finish();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Comment: I tried the app with my lg g4. Installed Android version is 6.0. Compiled sdk version in gradle file is 23.

Comment: This is the beginning of my Gradle File
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.gerding.test.dbperformancemessung"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

Comment: Hier mal zwei Links zu Screenshots. Im Ersten Bild wird die Erklärung angezeigt wofür die Berechtigung benötigt wird.
http://www.miger88.bplaced.net/Screenshot_2016-05-19-16-28-07.png
Das klappt auch.
Im zweiten Bild(sind aus einer anderen App)  sieht man den Dialog der mir leider fehlt.
http://www.miger88.bplaced.net/Screenshot_2016-05-19-16-28-11.png

Comment: Oh, my last comment was in german. The first link is a picture of the explanation that was shown. The second link displays the missing dialog for confirm or deny the permission. The pictures are from a second app where both work fine